# Set SECRET_KEY_BASE in production using a .env file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I've a `.env` file in my root folder in production. This file defines `SECRET_KEY_BASE` which is used in `config/secrets.yml`. The problem is that I can't manage to load my `.env` file before my `config/secrets.yml`. I've tried using the `dotenv` gem without success.

Any idea on how todo this in production?

I don't want to set it globally for my `webmaster` user on the production server. The `SECRET_KEY_BASE` value should only be accessable for by application.

I'm using rails 4.1.

Comment: Have you tried using `gem 'dotenv-rails'` in your gemfile?

Comment: @house9 Yes. That's the gem i'm using.

Comment: What are you using to deploy your application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I too use `dotenv` gem. It works for me in almost all case.

This is my configuration of `dotenv` gem (yes, i put `dotenv` in `Gemfile`). I just create an `aaaaa.rb` initializer file.

```
config/initializers/aaaaaa.rb
#obscure name because rails load initializers/* files based on alphabets 
 require 'dotenv'
 Dotenv.load
```

And, cases which it doesn't,  i do this this finally in  `config/boot.rb` file

```
ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] = "foobar"
```

Comment: Do you mind displaying the code used to load `dotenv` in production? I can't manage to load it in time before the `config/secrets.yml` file loads.

Comment: @Oleander , okay I have added relevant information.

Comment: Loading dotenv in production using a init file worked. I (for some reason) only tried loading it in the `application.rb` file, which didn't work. Thanks!

Comment: I get `cannot load such file -- dotenv` using your solution

Comment: i think you forgot to run `bundle install` after putting `dotenv` in `Gemfile`

Answer (score 2):

I was also having this problem.  Here is how I got it to work.  I followed documentation to [initialize dotenv early](https://github.com/bkeepers%20/dotenv#note-on-load-order):

```
# config/application.rb
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

Dotenv::Railtie.load

HOSTNAME = ENV['HOSTNAME']
```

But then I came across this [error (issue #155)](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv/issues/155):

```
gems/dotenv-rails-1.0.2/lib/dotenv/rails.rb:17:in `load': undefined method `join' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

The workaround (also documented in [issue #155](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv/issues/155)) is to replace `Dotenv::Railtie.load` with:

```
Dotenv.load(File.expand_path("../../.env.#{Rails.env}", __FILE__))
```

Apparently this is only a problem when using rails 4.1.

Answer (score -2):

Was also having this problem, but manage to get it to work by having this in my secrets.yml file:

```
production:
  secret_key_base: ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"]
```

It worked after removing the `<%= %>`

Comment: Actually, it just sets the secret key to be the `'ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"]'` string. And that's not especially secure.

Comment: Don't follow this answer. Read the comment above.