# Can't push to Heroku because of DOTENV uninitialized constant error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, recaptcha, uninitialized-constant

I am trying to push my project up to Heroku.  I have been using:

```
    gem 'dotenv-rails', :groups => [:development, :test]
```

Because I am using recpatcha and need to export my keys to the app in development.

When I try to push the code to heroku I noticed this error message:

```
    remote:  !     NameError: uninitialized constant Dotenv
```

So I commented out the Dotenv gem and any Dotenv variables in the app. I ran

```
    $ bundle exec rake -P
```

Then tried the push again.  I am still getting the same error from Heroku. Do I need to reset my gemfiles somehow?

Comment: May be this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/23439259/2681997

Comment: The thing is I have dotenv working fine, and I have set my heroku config with the keys, its just that when I push to heroku I get the uninitialized constant error.

Comment: see this comment from above mentioned answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23439148/set-secret-key-base-in-production-using-a-env-file/23439259#comment35939063_23439259

Comment: I am not sure how to load dotenv into production using an init file, can you explain what is meant there?

Comment: Ok. Into your `rails_project/cofig/ ` Create one file and named it `dotenv_load.rb` Into this new file paste this code `require 'dotenv' Dotenv.load`. Then find `secret_key_base` in your project. Copy the value of `secret_key_base` and paste this into `boot.rb` like this `ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] = "YOUR SECRET KEY BASE"`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, so the answer in the end was that I needed to change

```
    gem 'dotenv-rails', :groups => [:development, :test]
```

to

```
    gem 'dotenv-rails', :require => 'dotenv/rails-now'
```

which I think is another way of doing what you were suggesting there @ABPrime.  Thanks a lot for your help.